# Missing content in Keycloak themes folder

Tags: themes, keycloak

I am new to Keycloak, and I am trying to understand how to add additional attributes to the registration page in keycloak. As I understand it, this could be done by utilizing the register.ftl file in the themes folder. The problem is that this folder only includes a readme file and nothing else.

I am pretty sure that there are something about this whole thing that I am miss understanding, are there someone who could point me in the right direction?

I have the keycloak working fine, protecting a react app of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the README?

```
While creating custom themes, especially when overriding templates, it may be useful to use the built-in templates as
a reference. These can be found within the theme directory of '../lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-themes-20.0.3.jar', which can be opened using any
standard ZIP archive tool.

**Built-in themes should not be modified directly, instead a custom theme should be created.
```

Create your own theme in which you can then edit the register.ftl